# How decrypting work with specific algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, encryption, cryptography, password-encryption

I need help for little bit encryption.
Here is encryption algorithm:
(123 * char + 18) % 256

Here is decryption algorithm:
char = char -18
char = 179 * char % 256

I found decryption algorithm from you tube, because I couldn't find it myself. My question is I can not understand 179. Where it comes from, why 179 i can not understand. I tried to search from google, you tube to understand decrypting process but I couldn't get it. I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

179 is the multiplicative inverse to 123

123*179  % 256  = 1

Your calculations are all %256, so you cannot simply divide by 123. So you need to find the equivalent of 1/123 to multiply with. That's the 179. So multiply by 179 is the same as divide by 123 which is needed to reverse the multiplication of the encryption.

P.s
The `char -18` in your decryption algorithm is dangerous because the value might become negative which can lead to problems. Better you replace
`char = char -18`
by
`char = (char -18 +256) %256`
This way you always stay in the positive numbers.

Answer (score 2):

MrSmith42's answer hits all the high-points. This just expands on that and provides more links and search terms so you can learn more.

The system you're working with is called [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic). In that system, all numbers are between 0 and `n - 1` (`n` is 256 in this case), and adding "wraps around" so that `255 + 1 == 0`. (== here should be read as "is congruent with," but you can intuitively think of it as "equals," and I will call it equals here.)

Modular arithmetic is a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)). Addition works just like you expect from "normal" integers. It commutes (`a + b == b + a`). And every number has an additive inverse (a "negative"). When you add a number to its additive inverse, you get zero. In this sense, `255 == -1` because `1 + 255 == 0`. And so subtraction works just like you expect.

Modular arithmetic also has multiplication, which is just repeated addition. `2 * 6 == 12`, just like in "normal" integers. But it wraps around, so `100 * 200 == 32`. All good so far. Nothing particularly surprising.

But what about division? Subtraction is adding the additive inverse. In the same way, division is multiplying by the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). The additive inverse is that number you can add and get 0. The multiplicative inverse is that number you can multiply by and get 1.

123 and 179 are multiplicative inverses because `123 * 179 == 1`. And in this way, you can say that `123 == 1/179` and vice versa. So that's the answer to your question. But there's a little more that is important.

Since 256 is not prime, this "mod 256" space is a ring, but it is not a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)). Every number has an additive inverse, but not every (non-zero) number has a multiplicative inverse. For some non-zero numbers, `1/x` does not exist. For example, in mod 256, there is no such number as 1/2. There is no number you can multiply by 2 and get 1. But there is a number 1/3 (171).

In your encryption system, 123 cannot be arbitrarily replaced. There are only 65 pairs of values that "work." So 130 total values out of the 256 available. This is why in real systems based on modular arithmetic, `n` is generally a prime. When `n` is prime, this system is a field, and every non-zero value has an inverse.

Once you're comfortable with these basic concepts, you may want to explore the next step of modular exponentiation, which will lead you to the [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), which is an important concept in some important cryptosystems.